# Word wrap not working in firefox, tried everything

Tags: css, firefox, word-wrap

Hello I'm so utterly confused and I've searched around here for hours and tried everything, yes including rules specific for FF.

Here is my current class.

```
.paste_body
{
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-top: -30px;
margin-bottom: -10px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Before everyone goes on and starts giving me advice could you please take the time to real time CSS edit via inspect elm in fire fox to actually correctly answer this? because I've tried it all.

The URL is:
[skidpaste.org/QMGm3uOX](http://skidpaste.org/QMGm3uOX)

EDIT: Keep in mind this works in every other browser.

Comment: wraps in FF even if no spaces. Tried it just a second before with your css for `body` tag

Answer (score 3):

This happens because Firefox doesn't know where to create a line break since you don't have any spaces in your text strings. Although I tried your page in Chrome, and it "works", it certainly doesn't look very good...

Here is a link on how to deal with this in CSS:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

Comment: So it turns out that in firefox you cannot have a pre within a pre, so what I've done is changed the geshi lib around and instead replacing pre with div, works fine :) thanks for trying