# CSS property word-wrap not working for select element on Firefox

Tags: css, html-select

I have one html dropdown. In the dropdown, some of the options have long strings without any spaces. I want to wrap such options into the next line. I used the CSS `word-wrap` property. It works fine for me in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

I also tried using the `word-break` property as suggested [in the suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869653/word-wrap-not-working-in-firefox-tried-everything)

I also made [a demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatuiet/z7jj89ad/5/). It looks fine on Chrome, but if you open that demo on Firefox, the text fails to wrap. How can I fix this?

```css
.setWidth {
  width: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <select class="formNamesList setWidth" id="CustomCategories" name="CustomCategories" size="15">
    <option value="10085240">_1Test_Today</option>
    <option value="10085242">_1Test_Today_A</option>
    <option value="10085091" style="word-wrap:break-word">testcust_copyFinal_copytetshhshshshhshshhshshshhshshhshshhshshshshhshshshshhshshshshhshshhshs</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word wrap not working in firefox, tried everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869653/word-wrap-not-working-in-firefox-tried-everything)

Comment: I have seen that links. but no luck with the strings that dont have spaces @hbirjand

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your post to include the relevant HTML and CSS into a code snippet, in case people can't get to jsfiddle.net, which can happen in some corporate environments. I've also added text indicating you've looked at the suggested duplicate, which is always a good idea to avoid closure. I also updated the title to be more clear about what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 5):

***No,*** you cannot `wrap` the text in a native select. You can use [jquery plugins](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTs42/2/)
to achieve this. 
[Here are more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743676/html-listbox-wrap-text)

Still you may try this and see if it works:

***break-word***
    Indicates that normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line.

***pre***
    Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at 
 elements.

***pre-wrap***
    Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at 
, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```
  word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE*/
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
  white-space: pre-wrap;      /* other browsers */
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Kurenai. :)
 I tried your CSS solution.But that does not work.I think I need to take plugin help

Comment: That was the first line of my reply :). It is not possible to wrap in select tags.

Comment: CSS solution actually works except that some parts of the word is covered by the scroll bar